# How to output SVN branch name to textfile from Teamcity?

Tags: svn, teamcity

We have a teamcity Visual studio Build setup, which uses SVN for all the builds.

What I need to do is this:

After a successful build, I 'd like teamcity to create a text file in the folder where it checked out the build files from source control and INSERT the svn branch name.

For example, if the branch name is '10.2', teamcity should create a text file containing just the line '10.2'.

I guess I could , as a build step, run a dos batch file to create this text file, but how do I get the name of the branch which teamcity checked out for this build?

Thanks

Comment: Does `%teamcity.build.branch%` give you the right value? You can test this by simply adding a build step of type command line containing just `echo %teamcity.build.branch%` and checking the build log after a build.

Comment: Which OS is the agent running on? The command svn info does include the branch, so this could be parsed and output to the text file

Comment: Its on windows 2008 . %teamcity.build.branch% unfortunately doesn't work, it just queues the build, saying no build agents available. I am trying with other variables to see if something works :(

Answer (score 0):

You can use the parameter teamcity.branch.name or teamcity.build.branch (depending upon how you have setup your targets) and use a dos command to output this to a text file